# Extend python/django with c and mod_wsgi with apache

Tags: python, c, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a question about extending python with c code and mod_wsgi.

I have a django app in an apache server that query a postgresql database to generate reports. In some reports the system creates a csv file with the results. To create this csv file, some times the system must process more than two hundred thousands registers with python, that is obviously very slow. To accelerate this, we programed a c module that do this work, and that improves the speed many times. We have tried with ctypes and create a python module with c, both works fine in the runserver but crashes when executed with apache and mod_wsgi.

The error in httpd-error.log is:

[Wed Jul 27 02:33:52 2011] [notice] child pid 44657 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

¿Any suggestion?

The code is:

```
# Creates the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/x-zip-compressed')
response['Content-Disposition'] = \
    'attachment; filename=' + filename + '.zip'

p0 = 'descarga_' + str(datetime.today()) + '.csv'

p1 = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
p2 = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']

#lib.generar(string_at(p0),p1,p2,string_at(str(init)),string_at(str(end)),string_at(str(provider)))

import generador
generador.generar(p0,p1,p2,str(init),str(end),str(provider))
```

It crashes after we call generador.generar() that is an external module developed in C

I have also tried with GDb as @GrahamDumpleton suggets and this is the output, not very useful :(

The debugger starts and when i clic the link that executes that calls the c module it falls agin in segmentation fault

```
(gdb) run -X
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /usr/local/sbin/httpd -X
[New LWP 101064]
[New Thread 28501140 (LWP 101064)]


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 28501140 (LWP 101064)]
0x2847d423 in fwrite () from /lib/libc.so.7
```

Well after the Segmetation fault, I tried with the 'where' command in the debugger and this is what it give:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x2847d423 in fwrite () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x293f8d09 in generar () from /ruta/al/codigo/generador.so
#2  0x28912caa in PyCFunction_Call () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#3  0x2896e49a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#4  0x2897044b in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#5  0x288feafd in PyClassMethod_New () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#6  0x288d622c in PyObject_Call () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#7  0x2896c27a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#8  0x2896fadc in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#9  0x2897044b in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#10 0x288fea0a in PyClassMethod_New () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#11 0x288d622c in PyObject_Call () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#12 0x288e4fd8 in PyClass_IsSubclass () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#13 0x288d622c in PyObject_Call () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#14 0x2893044c in _PyObject_LookupSpecial () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#15 0x288d622c in PyObject_Call () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#16 0x28968ec4 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
#17 0x2889b229 in Adapter_run (self=0x28b4dd58, object=0x28c7d50c) at mod_wsgi.c:3841
#18 0x2889be50 in wsgi_execute_script (r=0x28cb4058) at mod_wsgi.c:6547
#19 0x2889de66 in wsgi_hook_handler (r=0x28cb4058) at mod_wsgi.c:9080
#20 0x08076b19 in ap_run_handler (r=0x28cb4058) at config.c:157
#21 0x08079dee in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x28cb4058) at config.c:376
#22 0x08084eb0 in ap_process_request (r=0x28cb4058) at http_request.c:282
#23 0x0808201b in ap_process_http_connection (c=0x28b201f0) at http_core.c:190
#24 0x0807de09 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x28b201f0) at connection.c:43
#25 0x08089791 in child_main (child_num_arg=Variable "child_num_arg" is not available.
) at prefork.c:662
#26 0x080899e3 in make_child (s=0x28510f10, slot=0) at prefork.c:707
#27 0x0808a591 in ap_mpm_run (_pconf=0x2850f018, plog=0x2853d018, s=0x28510f10) at  prefork.c:983
#28 0x08064195 in main (argc=676384792, argv=0x28b1e018) at main.c:739
```

Comment: Don't post the same question twice under two different (though similar) usernames. Just use one. Your other question is better asked and formatted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840682/how-to-use-c-python-extensions-with-django-and-in-apache.

Comment: Can you post the code? A segfault is basically impossible to diagnose without it.

Comment: @agf, that's probably my brother we are working together in this project

Comment: And you both posted the same question at the same time on the same site by accident?

Comment: @agf, no, we where talking about this, and said that we can ask in stackoverflow. I write this question (mi first question btw) and he also writes another before going to sleep surely (here is more than 3am).

Comment: @MorganHarris I have post the code, the c code is also needed?

Comment: When the error occurs in gdb, you should run the command 'where' or 'thread apply all bt' to get the stack trace. You still need to actually tell the debugger what you want once it crashes. If you are going to write C extensions, you really need to learn how to use the debugger properly.

Comment: Try and rebuild your extension module with debug symbols in it. See update to my answer below on how to do that. You can then use gdb to find out what variables are set to and work out from that what is getting screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

and forcing the application to run in main Python interpreter.

Possible your C extension isn't written properly to work with Python sub interpreters.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Your code could also just be buggy and using it under mod_wsgi shows out the problem where command line Python does.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB

on how to debug where the crash is occurring.

---

UPDATE 1

When building your extension module, to aid debugging in gdb, ensure that optimisation isn't turned on when compiling extension module and that debug options are.

For setup.py driven extension module build, I find it necessary to add:

```
from distutils import sysconfig
dummy = sysconfig.get_config_vars('CFLAGS', 'OPT')
config_vars = sysconfig._config_vars
config_vars['CFLAGS'] = config_vars['CFLAGS'].replace(' -Os ', ' ')
config_vars['OPT'] = config_vars['OPT'].replace(' -Os ', ' ')
```

That way can get rid of -Os options. Whether it is -Os or -O will depend on your Python installation.

Check then for -g in compiler options when extension module built and add it if need be.

Once that is done you can then use gdb to actually dump out values of variables, get actual line numbers etc.

Comment: ¡Thanks! I try with WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} but the systems crash again, current debugging with GDB, if you have more links about the API to extend Python with C and comon errors it wil be great!

Comment: As you should know, there is the Python documentation itself. In particular those on Extending and Embedding, and Python/C API. http://www.python.org/doc/

Comment: Whell, thanks, at the beggining we where not thinking about writing a C extension, but for perfomance we try it after we start processing millions of registers and the process becomes very slow.

Comment: Well, this problem is solved, there was some problems like C pointers that crash the app and we add "EnableSendfile on" in httpd.conf, Thanks!

Comment: If your code is buggy, having 'EnableSendfile' set to 'on' or changing what it is set to shouldn't make a difference. Changing the setting may make problem go away, but make some other change and will likely come back. So, what is the connection?